# Making a C library thread safe

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, shared-libraries

I am writing a shared library in C. I know C functions are not thread safe.

My library routines looks like,

```
struct lib_handle {
....
};

int lib_init(lib_handle **handle);
int lib_process(lib_handle *handle);
....
....
```

Every method takes a pointer to `lib_handle` object. All the state is stored inside this structure. No global variables are used.

I assume if each thread creates it's own `lib_handle` instances, multiple threads can use the library functions. Since each thread has it's own handle, everythibg should work.

I haven't validated this assumption yet. I am wondering what you guys think about this design and do you thing I can state my library as thread safe given each thread has it's own handles?

Any help would be great!

Comment: This library is not using any libraries other than SQLite. SQLite itself is thread safe.

Comment: Hey, +1, finally a sensible question.

Answer (score 4):

That will make data/state of library thread safe.

But you also have to make sure that your library uses threadsafe functions from other libraries, e.g. use `strtok_r` instead of `strtok`.

Comment: Yeah. You are correct. What about other functions standard library functions?

Comment: @Appu Mostly standard functions are thread-safe unless said otherwise. Best way is to look at man page of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Threads works in shared memory space. Unsafe objects are the objects which can be accessed by multiple threads simulteniously. So if you have single lib_handle object for each threads there will be no problems.

Answer (score 0):

If each thread has a private lib_handle object your library should be fully threadsafe; if you let several threads share lib_handle objects the person using your library can still makea thread safe program if she uses your library correctly (i.e. your library is not inherently thread-unsafe which it would be if you used e.g. global variables).

If this mode of operation (shared lib_handle) is interesting you should clearly separate the functions which only read the state of lib_handle and those which manipulate the state of lib_handle. The former needing a read lock and the latter needing a write lock (the calling scope must handle this).

For what it is worth I have used the pattern you describe quite a lot, and like it.